# Yocto: adding "tree" to image, where are output binaries?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

To better understand how Yocto works, I'm trying to do a very simple thing.
I want to add to my image the tool `tree`.
So far I did:

```
$ bitbake -s | grep tree
libhtml-tree-perl                                    :5.03-r0                          
libhtml-tree-perl-native                             :5.03-r0                          
tree                                                :1.7.0-r0
```

then I added `tree` to my `<image>.bb` file:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += " \
    tree \
"
```

Built `tree` and `<image>`:

```
$ bitbake tree
$ bitbake <image>
```

Now, searching into the `tmp` directory I'm expecting to find the binary of `tree` (at least the output of compilation):

```
$ find tmp/ -name tree -type f
tmp-glibc/pkgdata/stm32mp1-sw25v00/runtime/tree
tmp-glibc/pkgdata/stm32mp1-sw25v00/tree
tmp-glibc/sysroots-components/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4/tree/sysroot-providers/tree
```

But:

```
$ cat tmp-glibc/pkgdata/stm32mp1-sw25v00/runtime/tree
PN: tree
PV: 1.7.0
PR: r0
PKGV: 1.7.0
PKGR: r0.0
LICENSE: GPLv2
DESCRIPTION: A recursive directory listing command.
SUMMARY: A recursive directory listing command
RDEPENDS_tree: glibc (>= 2.28)
SECTION: console/utils
PKG_tree: tree
FILES_tree: /usr/bin/* /usr/sbin/* /usr/libexec/* /usr/lib/lib*.so.* /etc /com /var /bin/* /sbin/* /lib/*.so.* /lib/udev /usr/lib/udev /lib/udev /usr/lib/udev /usr/share/tree /usr/lib/tree/* /usr/share/pixmaps /usr/share/applications /usr/share/idl /usr/share/omf /usr/share/sounds /usr/lib/bonobo/servers
FILES_INFO: {"/usr/bin/tree": 47364}
FILERDEPENDSFLIST_tree: /usr/bin/tree
FILERDEPENDS_/usr/bin/tree_tree:  libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) libc.so.6 rtld(GNU_HASH)
PKGSIZE_tree: 47364

$ cat tmp-glibc/pkgdata/stm32mp1-sw25v00/tree
PACKAGES: tree-dbg tree-staticdev tree-dev tree-doc tree-locale tree

$ cat tmp-glibc/sysroots-components/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4/tree/sysroot-providers/tree
[it's empty]
```

**So... where is the binary file?**

Comment: First of, you don't need to do `bitbake tree` to have tree compiled if your image has `tree` in `IMAGE_INSTALL`. Yocto has the logic for that and will compile it for you and put it into the image.
Then, do you have rm_work in INHERIT in your local.conf for example? That might explain why you don't have things in tmp/work/... because all things are cleaned when successfully compiled and packaged.
Finally, maybe you're not looking into the right place? If there is a place those files should be found it's in $BASE_WORKDIR (use `bitbake -e <somerecipe> | grep -e "^BASE_WORKDIR"` to find it)

Comment: @qschulz, I begin to see the puzzle. Yes, I have `rm_work` in `INHERIT` and I found where is the `$BASE_WORKDIR`. Last question: if I add the package *after* I've already built the image, it's enough to `bitbake <image>` again? I really don't want to purge the whole `tmp`...

Comment: Then it all makes sense :) FYI, if you don't want to disable rm_work globally but only for a recipe, try to use RM_WORK_EXCLUDE (c.f. https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-rm-work).
If you do changes to files that are needed by Yocto for an image or a recipe, (e.g. IMAGE_INSTALL), Yocto will detect it and rebuild the image/recipe and its dependencies. If you have to purge tmp, something's wrong and has to be fixed. Either fixed on your side or reported to maintainers.

Comment: You're right. All works as expected, now that I understood how it works. Your should be answers rather than comments. I see myself writing this a lot of times recently :)